# Single click app to create and register Self Signed Certificate for HTTPS on localhost

Tags: windows, http

I have just spent a few hours following various "How to" guides, trying to create and register a Self Signed Certificate for HTTPS on localhost, to help me develop locally. None of them seem to work  and I am very frustrated.

is there a single click app to generate the certificate, register it, update IIS, etc?